# How do I create events in jQuery Mobile 1.4 Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I don't know how to use the function to set the selected date of the date input (Popup Datepicker), and set that date in the calendar below (Inline Datepicker). I have seen this function to set it: `_setDate`, or `_setDateDatepicker`, but I don't know how to implement it. Please, if someone could help me, I would appreciate it.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "both",
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    maxDate: '+0',
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    regional: 'uk',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>Popup Datepicker</h2>
    <div data-demo-html="true">
        <input type="date" id="date_val" data-role="datebox" style="margin-top: 10px" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useNewStyle":true,"useFocus": true}'>
    </div>

    Evento: 
    <input type="text" id="event" name="event">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="   Enviar   " onClick="myFunction()">

    <h2>Inline Datepicker</h2>
    <div data-demo-html="true">
        <input type="text" id="cal" data-role="date" data-inline="true">
    </div>
```

Comment: have you found the solution? I also need to implement `onSelect` but still don't have any clue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the same functions as a regular datepicker.

Initialize the datepicker with the `defaultDate` option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: +7
});
```

Get or set the `defaultDate` option, after initialization:

```
// Getter
var defaultDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +7 );
```

[Source](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

Update: Just found some methods that might be useful

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

[API reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)